# How to push id of parent object to child objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have an array of object which has an inner array of object, I want to push the id of parent object to each child object.

```
   a = [
        {id: 'abc', stage: [{name: 'car' , value: '123'},{name: 'bus' , value: '345'},{name: 'truck' , value: '567'}],
        {id: 'def', stage: [{name: 'bike' , value: '890'},{name: 'cycle' , value: '123'},{name: 'car' , value: '456'}]}
    ]

expected output = [
    {name: 'car' , value: '123', id: 'abc'},{name: 'bus' , value: '345', 'abc'},{name: 'truck' , value: '567', 'abc'}, {name: 'bike' , value: '890', id: 'def'},{name: 'cycle' , value: '123',id: 'def',id: 'def'},{name: 'car' , value: '456', id: 'def'}
]
```

Im able to get the only the stage but not able to push id to each object. pls help

```
const getAllStages = [].concat(...map(a, el => el.stage));
console.log(getAllStages )
```

Comment: What is `map()`?

Comment: its lodash map.. import { map } from 'lodash'; 
for angular

Comment: Why concat to an empty array? Cut that step out: `[ ...map(...) ]`, or even just the `map(...)` itself which returns an array anyway is what you want.

Comment: If you're using Lodash, even easier: `_.map(a, 'stage')`. Done.

Comment: okay.... but i want id to be added to each object. now im getting only the stages

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.map()` again to add `el.id` to each element of `el.stage`.

You can use `.flatMap()` in the outer mapping to concatenate all the results into a single array.

```js
const a = [
    {id: 'abc', stage: [{name: 'car' , value: '123'},{name: 'bus' , value: '345'},{name: 'truck' , value: '567'}]},
    {id: 'def', stage: [{name: 'bike' , value: '890'},{name: 'cycle' , value: '123'},{name: 'car' , value: '456'}]}
]

result = a.flatMap(({
  id,
  stage
}) => stage.map(s => ({
  id: id,
  ...s
})));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Bracket-heavy to the point of bordering on LISP, but that destructuring is pretty concise!

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this without using libraries

```
let a = [
    {
        id: 'abc', stage:
            [
                { name: 'car', value: '123' },
                { name: 'bus', value: '345' },
                { name: 'truck', value: '567' }
            ]
    },
    {
        id: 'def', stage:
            [
                { name: 'bike', value: '890' },
                { name: 'cycle', value: '123' },
                { name: 'car', value: '456' }
            ]
    }
]    
let output = [];
    for (const element of a) {
        for (const stageElement of element.stage) {
            let newElement = {
                name: stageElement.name,
                value: stageElement.value,
                id: element.id
            };
            output.push(newElement);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Much easier with `map` and `...`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to merge in `id`:

```js
let remapped = a.map(e => ({ id: a.id, ...e }));
```

Where that converts each entry into an object inheriting the `a.id` value and adding on whatever else is in the object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example and result :)

```
a.forEach(function(row) {
    row.stage.map(function (child) {child.id = row.id})
})
```

result:

```
[{"id":"abc","stage":[{"name":"car","value":"123","id":"abc"},{"name":"bus","value":"345","id":"abc"},{"name":"truck","value":"567","id":"abc"}]},{"id":"def","stage":[{"name":"bike","value":"890","id":"def"},{"name":"cycle","value":"123","id":"def"},{"name":"car","value":"456","id":"def"}]}]
```

Comment: `forEach` on a `map`? The `map` result is discarded in this code. You're also jamming `id` into each element, permanently.

Comment: @tadman actually vishnu need exactly like that, thats why I use in this way

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = [
    {id: 'abc', stage: [{name: 'car' , value: '123'},{name: 'bus' , value: '345'},{name: 'truck' , value: '567'}]},
    {id: 'def', stage: [{name: 'bike' , value: '890'},{name: 'cycle' , value: '123'},{name: 'car' , value: '456'}]}
]

a.forEach(item => {
    const itemId = item.id;
    const stages = item.stage;

    stages.forEach(stage => {
        stage['id'] = itemId;
    })
});

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-custom-trigger-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-custom-trigger-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-custom-trigger-example.css'],
})

export class SelectCustomTriggerExample {

  @ViewChild('search') searchTextBox: ElementRef;

  selectFormControl = new FormControl();
  searchTextboxControl = new FormControl();
  selectedValues = [];
  data: string[] = [
    'A1',
    'A2',
    'A3',
    'B1',
    'B2',
    'B3',
    'C1',
    'C2',
    'C3'
  ]

  filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    /**
     * Set filter event based on value changes 
     */
    this.filteredOptions = this.searchTextboxControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith<string>(''),
        map(name => this._filter(name))
      );
  }

  /**
   * Used to filter data based on search input 
   */
  private _filter(name: string): String[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();
    // Set selected values to retain the selected checkbox state 
    this.setSelectedValues();
    this.selectFormControl.patchValue(this.selectedValues);
    let filteredList = this.data.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
    return filteredList;
  }

/**
 * Remove from selected values based on uncheck
 */
  selectionChange(event) {
    if (event.isUserInput && event.source.selected == false) {
      let index = this.selectedValues.indexOf(event.source.value);
      this.selectedValues.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }

  openedChange(e) {
    // Set search textbox value as empty while opening selectbox 
    this.searchTextboxControl.patchValue('');
    // Focus to search textbox while clicking on selectbox
    if (e == true) {
      this.searchTextBox.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Clearing search textbox value 
   */
  clearSearch(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.searchTextboxControl.patchValue('');
  }

  /**
   * Set selected values to retain the state 
   */
  setSelectedValues() {
    console.log('selectFormControl', this.selectFormControl.value);
    if (this.selectFormControl.value && this.selectFormControl.value.length > 0) {
      this.selectFormControl.value.forEach((e) => {
        if (this.selectedValues.indexOf(e) == -1) {
          this.selectedValues.push(e);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
/**  Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      @for (option of filteredOptions | async; track option) {
        <mat-option [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
      }
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>  myControl = new FormControl('');
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value || '')),
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  constructor(
    private _loading: LoadingService
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this._loading.setLoading(true, request.url);
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(catchError((err) => {
        this._loading.setLoading(false, request.url);
        return err;
      }))
      .pipe(map<HttpEvent<any>, any>((evt: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
          this._loading.setLoading(false, request.url);
        }
        return evt;
      }));
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).